# Multiple non-static callbacks of C++ member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, callback, asynccallback

I have found that using the code in the linked answer/below works well, but has problems in my use case.  It effectively creates a "static wrapper" to a non-static member function, to be passed as a callback.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct Callback;
template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
struct Callback<Ret(Params...)> {
   template <typename... Args>
   static Ret callback(Args... args) {
      return func(args...);
   }
   static std::function<Ret(Params...)> func;
};
template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
std::function<Ret(Params...)> Callback<Ret(Params...)>::func;
```

So I have that bit in a header file and then various classes have code like below.  The problem is that when trying to define two such callbacks within the same scope the second overrides the first.

```
typedef int (*callback_t)(int*,int*);

Callback<int(int*,int*)>::func = std::bind(&myClass::myMethod1, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
callback_t func1 = static_cast<callback_t>(Callback<int(int*,int*)>::callback);      
register_task1_with_library(func1);

Callback<int(int*,int*)>::func = std::bind(&myClass::myMethod2, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
callback_t func2 = static_cast<callback_t>(Callback<int(int*,int*)>::callback);      
register_task2_with_library(func2);
```

The callback registered first is redirected to the second.  **What is the minimal change to create a second "static wrapper" for something like this?**  It seems the entire contents of the header file have to be duplicated, replacing Callback with something like Callback2, to have a second "static wrapper" available.

And an easier example to work with that shows the same problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "callback.hpp"
void print1(std::string msg)
{
    std::cout << "print1:\t" << msg << std::endl;
}
void print2(std::string msg)
{
    std::cout << "print2:\t\t" << msg << std::endl;
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    typedef void (*callback_t)(std::string);
    Callback<void(std::string)>::func = std::bind(print1, std::placeholders::_1);
    callback_t func1 = static_cast<callback_t>(Callback<void(std::string)>::callback);

    Callback<void(std::string)>::func = std::bind(print2, std::placeholders::_1);
    callback_t func2 = static_cast<callback_t>(Callback<void(std::string)>::callback);

    func1("howdy");
    func2("partner");
    return 0;
}
```

Related items: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29817048/2725742 and
[Using a c++ class member function as a c callback function, thread safe version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41198854/2725742)

The modified templates are below are what I ended up with after a  comment discussion and my testing suggests it is fine in my use cases.  The added 'tag' parameter helps keep each item unique.

```
template <typename T, int tag = 0>
struct Callback;
template <typename Ret, typename... Params, int tag>
struct Callback<Ret(Params...), tag> {
   template <typename... Args>
   static Ret callback(Args... args) {
      return func(args...);
   }
   int m_tag = tag;
   static std::function<Ret(Params...)> func;
};
template <typename Ret, typename... Params, int tag>
std::function<Ret(Params...)> Callback<Ret(Params...), tag>::func;
```

Comment: You could give `Callback` an extra template parameter, say `template <typename T, int tag = 0> struct Callback;`. Then you can stamp out separate instances simply by giving them distinct tags.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that sounds great, but I am doing something wrong.  The compiler tells me I am supplying 2 template arguments and it should be 1.  As suggested I changed ```template <typename T, int tag = 0> struct Callback;``` and then the first line when setting it up ```Callback<void(std::string), 3>::func = std::bind(print1, std::placeholders::_1);```

Comment: Did you also add the tag parameter to the specialization?

Comment: No, I did not follow through well on that, but updated my question with what I ended up with and is working.  If you "answer" the question I will select it as a solution.