# How to cast "void (MyClass::*)(int)" to "void (*)(int)"?

Tags: c++, templates

I've looking for how to cast class member to C-style callback.

Recentrly i found answer with special bind hack allows to bind class members to C-style callbacks:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39524069/5405443

I have this working code to bind function **MyClass::f**  to C function **f**:
But i want to avoid explicit passing cb_type as template parameter to c_bind function.
In provided example **CB** has type **void (*)(int)** and **Func** template parameter has **void (MyClass::*)(int)** type.

```
template<typename CB, typename Func, typename... Params>
CB* c_bind(std::_Bind<Func(Params...)> function) {
    return Callback<typename ActualType<CB>::type, __COUNTER__, Func>::getCallback(function);
}

typedef void (cb_type)(int);

class MyClass {
public:
    void f(int x) {
        std::cout << "Hello from MyClass::f(int), value: " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc;

    auto f = c_bind<cb_type>(std::bind(&MyClass::f, mc, std::placeholders::_1));
    //                ^ how to avoid explicit callback type declaration here?
    f(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Also i found this piece of code (https://gist.github.com/vikchopde/73b62314379f733e8938f11b246df49c) for "unwrapping" some kind of functions.

```
bool ok = fu::is_unwrappable<decltype(&MyClass::f)>::value; // always false
// fu::unwrap_function<decltype(&MyClass::f)>::type::function_ptr blah; // won't compile
```

but it won't work by unknown to me reason.

My question is there any workaround to extract return type and args list from type with class-memeber pointer like **void (MyClass::*)(int)** and contruct C-like type **void (*)(int)** ?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You are not going to figure this out via random Google searches, and by reading random code on Github. You need to thoroughly and fundamentally understand ***why*** you cannot cast it like this, and what `std::bind` does, and how it works in this case. You need to understanding ***the fundamental principles*** involved, which should be [fully explained in every good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You may not want to hear someone telling you "go read a book and learn this", but this what you must do, in order to do this correctly.

Comment: I used to know how to do this, I'll have to dig up the code.

 It involves making a bit of machine code in a struct adding the pointer to the object. Calling PrestoChangoSelector. Then typecasting the struct to a C function. The idea is the C function gets called, the object is pushed on the stack with the parameters, then the C++ function is called (via a jump instruction).

Comment: Sorry, with the DarkMode I thought this was Reddit!

Comment: `std::_Bind` is an implementation detail of the standard library implementation. You are not supposed to use it in your code. Instead use a lambda and `std::function` as the linked code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i would like to thank @Dappur for nice example. Using your guide i will rewrite my ugly bind interface with std::_Bind usage later. Also i want to thank @Sam Varshavchik for mentioning that set of C++ books. I'll start reading it to become C++ grandmaster like you to learn how "**why i cannot cast it like this**". But unfortunately with my poor c++ experience I can still do it now. Here is working code:

```
template<class T, unsigned int n, class CallerType>
struct CallbackWrapper;

template<class Ret, class... Params, unsigned int n, class CallerType>
struct CallbackWrapper<Ret(Params...), n, CallerType> {
    static auto get(std::function<Ret(Params...)>&& fn) -> Ret(*)(Params...) {
        func = fn;
        return static_cast<Ret(*)(Params...)>(CallbackWrapper<Ret(Params...), n, CallerType>::callback);
    }

private:
    static std::function<Ret(Params...)> func;

    static Ret callback(Params... args) {
        return func(args...);
    }
};

template<class Ret, class... Params, unsigned int n, class CallerType>
std::function<Ret(Params...)> CallbackWrapper<Ret(Params...), n, CallerType>::func;

template<typename T>
struct lambda_to_stdf {
    using type = void;
};

template<typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct lambda_to_stdf<Ret(Class::*)(Args...) const> {
    using type = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
};

template<class Ret, class Cls, class... Args1, class... Args2>
auto c_bind(std::_Bind<Ret(Cls::*(Cls, Args1...))(Args2...)> function) -> Ret(*)(Args2...) {
    return CallbackWrapper<Ret(Args2...), __COUNTER__, Ret(Cls::*(Cls, Args1...))(Args2...)>::get(std::move(function));
}

template<class Ret, class... Args>
auto c_bind(std::function<Ret(Args...)> function) -> Ret(*)(Args...) {
    return CallbackWrapper<Ret(Args...), __COUNTER__, std::function<Ret(Args...)>>::get(std::move(function));
}

template<class F>
auto c_bind(F function) -> decltype(c_bind((typename lambda_to_stdf<decltype(&F::operator())>::type)(function))) {
    return c_bind((typename lambda_to_stdf<decltype(&F::operator())>::type)(function));
}
```

Usage:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void f(int x) {
        std::cout << "Hello from MyClass::f(int), value: " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc;

    auto f = c_bind(std::bind(&MyClass::f, mc, std::placeholders::_1));
    f(10);

    std::function<void(int)> stdf = [](int v) {
        std::cout << "hello from std::function, value: " << v << std::endl;
    };
    auto f2 = c_bind(stdf);
    f2(100);

    auto f3 = c_bind([](int v) -> int {
        std::cout << "hello from lambda, value: " << v << std::endl;
        return 5.0f;
    });
    f3(1000);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in C++17, you are allowed to pass an arbitrary non-type parameter to a class with `template<auto>`. Therefore, we could store `MyClass::f` as a template parameter and parse its type with `decltype`. After passing this type to another templated class, we are able to extract desired types using template specialization.

The code below shows how to construct a C-style function `wrapper<>::func_type`.

Since you seem to bind an object to its member function, I additionally write the demo code to do this by invoking `wrapper<>::bind`. Hope it helps.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void f(int x) {
    std::cout << "Hello from MyClass::f(int), value: " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

void f(int x) {
    std::cout << "Hello from f(int), value: " << x << std::endl;
}

template<auto F>
struct wrapper
{
    template<typename> struct inner;

    template<class Cls, typename Ret, typename... Args>
    struct inner<Ret(Cls::*)(Args...)>
    {
        using func_type = Ret(Args...);

        static auto bind(Cls *obj)
        {
            return [=](Args ...args){
                return (obj->*F)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            };
        }
    };

    using func_type = typename inner<decltype(F)>::func_type;
    static const constexpr auto bind = inner<decltype(F)>::bind;
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc;

    auto h = wrapper<&MyClass::f>::bind(&mc);
    h(10);

    using func_t = typename wrapper<&MyClass::f>::func_type;
    std::function<func_t> g = f;
    g(1);
    return 0;
}
```