# C++ function pointer to C pointer in a general way

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an embedded C generated source file that requires a function pointer.
I need to give it a member function pointer from my C++ code.
One of the solution I encountered was: [Convert C++ function pointer to c function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808054/convert-c-function-pointer-to-c-function-pointer) . Specifically this one:

```
class MyCallbackClass
{

    void non_static_func(/* args */);

public:
    static void static_func(MyClass *ptr, /* other args */) {
        non_static_func(/* other args */);
    }
};
```

and giving the C function : `c_library_function(MyCallabckClass::static_func)`

This suits my system, as I am using c++11 , but can not involve any external libraries (`std`, `bind`), or heap allocation.

I would like to make it more general to any C callback I might need in the future.

How can I build `MyCallbackClass`  according to the C typedef of the function pointer? so I can give it my C++ member function (of the same type) ? e.g.,

```
typedef int32_t (*Write_Func)(uint16_t, uint16_t, const uint8_t*, uint16_t);
```

Comment: Unless you have some way to pass a "user data" pointer to the callback, I don't see a nice way to do it.

Comment: Callback functions in C often take a `void*` as one of the arguments. Does your C function do that?

Comment: Unfortunately not, what is the void for?

Comment: How is C going to execute member functions when it doesn't have the concept of members or classes to begin with? Though I think some Danish guy designed a "C with classes language" at some point, maybe worth checking out :)

Comment: On a serious note, the common way to deal with this _is_ to pass along a `static` member function. That can be called from C just fine. Though I'm not sure how you'll sort out the C++ code `non_static_func` from a `static` member in the first place.

Comment: @ShantiSchul The `void*` is for used to cast into some user defined type. It's very common to supply a `static` C++ member function, then cast the `void*` to the class type and call a non-`static` member function

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , maybe something similar I can use ? I don't want to have to write a new class for each callback..

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, can a C code somehow run a static member function without the void ptr of the class? Or must it have ptr->static_func to run?

Comment: @ShantiSchul It can run a `static` member function ([like this](https://godbolt.org/z/bxa3P7bqG))  and if it's supposed to use non-`static` member data, it must have a way to access the actual instance of the class (like the example shows). Without supplying a pointer to the instance you could use a global pointer that you use inside the function, but that is ugly and doesn't work well if you want to be able to use multiple instances.

Comment: @TedLyngmo appreciate the detailed answer, is there a possibility to save the user data as a static as well?  static void ptr = this?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i see the problem then, all classes instances will have the same void ptr if I make it static... Any way to change a static between classes...I guess not ...

Comment: If designing a C wrapper "class" using opaque pointers, then you can allocate one wrapper per C++ object and initialize it through a void pointer obtained from a C++ getter returning `this`. The C wrapper could then pass this pointer along to a callback corresponding to a static member. With that design you'd allow for multiple instances and it would be thread safe. But it's needlessly complicated and a last resort.

Comment: Where's the _"C generated source file"_ coming from? Can you convince the creator to make it possible to supply user data via a `void*`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo STsemiconductors..., I have the code, but if I change it , and they future change it, then it can be a mess.

Comment: @Lundin, not sure but if I template the class according to the C typedef?  I can store the instance of the member function as static inside my callback class?

Comment: @ShantiSchul Given the limitations you provided (no bind, lambda et.c) the example you posted is the only way to do this.

Comment: Ok, will leave this to be . thanks all